# Can't get iframe content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to print iframe response code with javascript
this is my code

```
var iframe;

iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json';
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Why are you styling `display = 'none'?`

Comment: `iframe.style.display = 'none';` that should be the reason

Comment: i don't know....what i have to do?

Comment: remove that line

Comment: ok i remove it..then?

Comment: We would need more details to answer that. Where are you running this code? Basically you need to refresh the code, e.g. save the code and let it run again. But hard to answer because of you let's say doing this in console it should refresh automatically

Comment: i'm running it in html file...

Comment: Any output in the console?

Comment: When I try it I get >Refused to frame 'https://api.ipify.org/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://www.odwebp.svc.ms/share".
but I don't have the same context as you. You could be trying something that is insecure and the browser won't let you do it

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe;

iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

console.log(iframe)
```

The following code gives the result you want, also you can see in the console that the iframe actually exists on the page. Probably the reason why nothing shows up is the endpoint/url you are using. Try some website like google, yahoo and it will display fine.

Comment: ok i test it , i can see some stuff....but i need to see the iframe content in alert

Comment: Then why do you use iframe for that? Just show the alert after getting data from the endpoint.